# How to hide Forecast Object?

Tags: forecast

I want to hide the forecast object in the lightning app launcher. Before I did anything, I noticed there were Two Forecast links on the app launcher. After I set the Forecast Tab into 'Tab Hidden' , only one Forecast was sort of hidden yet the other Forecast Link still remains. The Forecast object was supposed to be hidden in order to remove access to it. Can anyone please help me on how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation in Lightning.It will still display regardless of setting.

Please check the below link:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_gaps_limitations_nav_actions.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=208.8

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A0000008gSpQAI